# Unexpected behavior of css float

Tags: html, css, css-float

Here is my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwJjY/)

I just have 3 `div`s. The 2nd `div` is floated to the right, and 3rd `div` appears just below the 2nd.

In the 3rd `div`, I am setting `margin-top` property, and this property does not have any effect on the layout.

*Question*: Can someone explain me understanding this behavior of float?

**HTML**

```
<div class="header">
</div>
<div class="sidebar">
</div>
<div class="footer">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #abcdef;
}

.sidebar {
    margin-top: 15px;
    float: right;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #abcdef;
    display: block;
}

.footer {
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #000000;
}
```

Comment: Set 3rd div position to relative.

Comment: @AliK: that doesn't fix anything.

Comment: fwiw, HTML5 has `<header>`,`<footer>`, and `<aside>` tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not unexpected at all. The `.sidebar` is removed from regular flow layout by its `float` property, as such it doesn't take up any space anymore. The `.footer` has a `clear` rule, so it is forced underneath any floats, but that automatically puts it 215px (margin+height of the sidebar) behind the last element that ***is*** part of the flow layout. As such its margin requirement of 20px is completely satisfied, and it appears at its logical current position. You can verify this by setting the top margin to 220px instead, it will appear 5px (220-215) below the sidebar.

You can easily achieve the effect you desire by putting `margin-bottom:20px` on the sidebar since it will then be required to keep that distance to the footer, pushing it down.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to the clear rule.

> [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins) - An element that has had clearance applied to it never
>   collapses its top margin with its parent block's bottom margin.

Baiscally, if you want to use clear, the general rule is to add an element between the two floated divs to ensure you can correctly space them.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by the fact that floated elements aren't really there with respect to margin calculations. Your .footer is below whatever unfloated elements are above it, (with a margin of 20px). This issue is caused because margins with respect to floats are calculated relative to other floats, (not all other elements). 
So to get the desired effect add a margin-bottom element to .sidebar, have a meaningless float added to the .footer, or add a

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

between the .footer and .sidebar

Comment: Having a 'non-essential' `<br>` just for the purpose of layout is worse than using a `<div>` since the first has padding of its own by default.

Comment: Fair enough. I actually use the padding provided by the br in my layouts. In this case you're right though, and I've edited it to be better for their question.

Comment: In general, CSS3 has enough mature ways to make 'spacer elements' and such obsolete. I haven't used any for several months now (being a professional webdeveloper).

Answer (score 0):

The top margin of the footer div is being collapsed, http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html#collapsing-margins

If you add margin-bottom to the sidebar instead of the top of the footer it will work.